# Function growing faster for negative inputs than for positives

Tags: loss-function

I am working on a regression problem where I want to model the loss function in a way that it "punishes" to big errors much more than small errors (so I am in the realm of exponential functions) but also in a way that is punishes a negative error much more than a positive error.

So for example:

- Prediction off by +4.0: is a problem, but still ok
- Prediction off by +0.5: not a big deal
- Prediction off by -0.5: is a problem, but still ok
- Prediction off by -4.0: is a major problem

My problem is that I cant find a good function to describe this. x squared and so do not have the higher values for negative inputs that I am looking for.

My best workaround for now is to just move the whole function to the right (x-2)^​2, but there must be something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible using a piecewise exponential loss, something like this:

$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^2 & x < 0\\
\lambda x^2 & x \ge 0
\end{cases}
$

with $0 < \lambda < 1$. A $\lambda$ of around 0.02 should roughly give you the scale you want.

[image]